# Optional parameter in Partial Function?

Tags: scala

My team develop kind of "core" project, which is being used by a couple of our other projects.
It is the reason, why we dont want to change keenly some method signatures.

Let's assume we have method like this:

```
override def calculateNextStep: PartialFunction[(Option[OrderType], Option[OrderState]), OrderType] = {
    case (Some(OrderTypeX), Some(InProgress))  => SomeOrderTypeA
    case (Some(OrderTypeY), Some(Done)) => SomeOrderTypeB
    case (None, None) => SomeOrderTypeC
}
```

But now I need to override this method in one of "non core" projects - I need add one extra parameter - let say parentOrder.
It is necessary to calculate next step properly. But I wouldn't like to affect other projects.
It would be great to add new optional parameter (with default value None) and dont affect other projects.
Is any way to to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why just do not provide another method which calls this one?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Because this method makes no sense without new, extra parameter. Extra parameter (ParentOrder) has information about action type: creation, modification etc. Base on this value we are able to calculate next steps.

Comment: If you change the arguments of a method when overriding then you are not respecting Liskov, then you have a failed abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot change method signature when overriding. Try overloading instead like so

```
def calculateNextStep(a: Option[OrderType], b: Option[OrderState] c: Option[ParentOrder]): OrderType = 
  (a, b, c) match {
    case (Some(OrderTypeX), Some(InProgress), Some(aParentOrder)) => // do something
    case _ => calculateNextStep(a, b)
  }
```